# How to skip xml attribute or element when generating xml in SAP BODS?

Tags: xml, sap-bw, sap-data-services

I am trying to figure out how I can skip an attribute or element writing on to XML. For ex:

```
<File>
  <data>
    <name>...</name>
    <id>...</id>
  </data>
  <noData>..</noData>
</File>
```

`<noData>` is enumerated and can only accept 'Y' and this needs to be populated only when there are no records to write in `<data>.` In other words if values are populated for `<data>` then I need to skip `<noData>` or if count of records is 0 then I need to skip `<data>` and populate `<noData>` with 'Y'.

I am trying to achieve this SAP BODS but no luck so far.

Can you help?

Basically want to understand how will I skip the elements writing onto XML if their values are not populated or they got null values.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out answer for this. This can be done using `<choice>...</choice>` in xsd. This means either `data or noData` is populated.

To achieve this on to SAP BODS.. I have used a conditional workflow to populate `noData` attribute incase of 0 records or `data` attribute incase of non zero records.

```
<File>
<choice>
<data>
<name>...</name>
<id>...</id>
</data>
<noData>..</noData>
</choice>
</File>
```